# How to configure SSH to connect through an OpenVPN?

Tags: ssh, openvpn, openssh

I have a desktop at work that I like to keep synchronized with my home computers using Unison, which connects through SSH. I also sometimes like to remote in to the work computer using SSH.

My work network is starting a new policy that will only allow connections from outside the network if they are over a VPN.

Is there a way that I can adjust my SSH configuration so that whenever it tries to log in to the work computer, it goes through the work VPN?

To be clear, I do not want to have to manually connect to the work VPN each time I want SSH to connect to the work computer. I also do not want to be permanently connected to the work VPN.

Note that I can freely change both the client (my home computers) and server (work computer) SSH configurations. Also, I don't think it should matter, but all machines in question are Linux boxes. I am using OpenSSH and the work VPN is openVPN.

Clarification: The main reason I want to not be permanently connected to the work VPN is to not have to worry about following their terms of service. So I want only the SSH traffic to be sent through the VPN and nothing else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several options come to my mind.

#### Shell Script

you could write a shell script which

- starts openVPN
- starts SSH
- stops openVPN when SSH disconnects

  `#!/bin/bash
  /usr/bin/openvpn /home/user/ovpn/config.ovpn
  ssh user@host
  pkill -SIGTERM -f 'openvpn --conf /home/user/ovpn/config.ovpn'`

After that, you can alias that, e.g. `alias vpnssh='/home/scriptname.sh'`, and/or add that to your `.bashrc`.

#### Proxycommand

You can try to use openSSH's `proxycommand`for that:

`ssh -o ProxyCommand="/usr/bin/openvpn /home/user/ovpn/config.ovpn" user@host`

#### in both cases

you need to tell openVPN that you do not want to route everything through the tunnel. So, given that 192.168.0.1 is your work desktop, add the following to your openVPN config file

`route-nopull 
route 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.255`

use `route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0` if you want to reach the whole subnet.

Comment: Are these solutions going to make my *entire* connection go through the VPN? I don't want that to happen because I don't want to be subject to my work's terms of service.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, I literally _knew_ that I forgot something. Thanks for the reminder. I will update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a client PC that is connected to an OpenVPN server/host via a tunnel.

For SSH through the VPN tunnel: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069846/connected-to-openvpn-server-but-cant-ssh

On the Openvpn host:

```bash
$sudo ufw enable    
$ sudo ufw allow 1194/udp comment "Allowing OpenVPN Connections"    
$ sudo ufw allow from 10.8.0.1/24 to any port 22 proto tcp comment "SSH allowed for VPN clients"
```

On the client side:

Make sure OpenSSH is installed and running and port 22 is open on the firewall.

Then:

```bash
$ ssh user@10.8.0.1       (change “user” to your login name on the server/host).
```